# Cannot get information in mysql result with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

I'm using Rails with ActiveAdmin gem. And I want to select some information from mysql database.

```
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection();
s="SELECT word FROM dics WHERE word LIKE 'tung%'";
ten = sql.execute(s);
```

But when I printed out "ten" to screen, it showed that:

```
#<Mysql2::Result:0x4936260>
```

How can I get the information of records?

Comment: What does your model look like? Did you try `Dic.where( "word LIKE 'tung%' ).all`? For a query this simple there's almost certainly no reason to use SQL directly.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use models syntax? Like `Dic.select(:word).where(["word LIKE ?", "tung%"])`. Do you actually have a model Dic?

Comment: I used it before, and it also printed out `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x238cab8>`, do u have any idea?

Comment: @TidusLe as per you last comment: if you receive a relation, try calling `.all` or `.first` to instantiate actual records implicitly referenced relation object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you don't use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` directly. Sticking with ARel syntax should work for most cases, and your example doesn't seem like an edge case.

As stated in the comments above, try the following:

```
dics = Dic.select(:word).where(["word LIKE ?", "tung%"]).all
```

In order to pluck some special field of object, not objects themselves, use `pluck` instead of `all`:

```
# instead of .pluck(:word) use real field identifier
dics = Dic.where(["word LIKE ?", "tung%"]).pluck(:word)
```

Comment: when I use `.all`, the result looks like that `[#<Task TaskID: "SP001">, #<Task TaskID: "SP002">]`. How can I get exactly `SP001`, or `SP002`?